# Cumulative masking for Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Let's say I have a Texture2D object. What I want to be able to do is to mask it using another Texture2D object (I already have a basic masking shader written), and then assign this new masked texture to the original Texture2D. At the next iteration, I then could be able to do this again but for another mask, and again, and again...

Drawing all the masks in a single texture using RenderTexture is not possible since 1) there would be huge performances issues 2) they are generated at runtime.

Here's what I want to do:

[image: Cumulative masking]

Does anyone else ever had this problem or know a solution? Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

Here's what I'm doing for now:

```
// Ok, so GroundLayer is a layer that setup GroundZones. GroundZones are ’slices’ of the screen that can be ‘dug’
// into, the act of digging being masking the main ground texture with another texture containing only a line.
// This is where cumulative masking come handy, since we don’t want to have to track each point where the user
// dug. We want to create a sort of mutable texture, but simpler.
void GroundLayer::digLine(Point start, Point end) {

    // To dig a line, we need first to get the texture of the zone we will be digging into. Then we get the
    // relative position of the start and end point in the zone's node space. Finally we use the custom shader to
    // draw a mask over the existing texture.
    for (auto it = _children.begin(); it != _children.end(); it++) {

        GroundZone *zone = static_cast<GroundZone *>(*it); // We are sure that all the children are GroundZones

        Point nodeStart = zone->convertToNodeSpace(start);
        Point nodeEnd = zone->convertToNodeSpace(end);

        // Now that we have our two points converted to node space, it's easy to draw a mask that contains a line
        // going from the start point to the end point and that is then applied over the current texture.
        Size groundZoneSize = zone->getContentSize();
        RenderTexture *rt = RenderTexture::create(groundZoneSize.width, groundZoneSize.height);
        rt->retain();
        rt->beginWithClear(0, 0, 0, 0); {

            // Draw a line going from start and going to end in the texture, the line will act as a mask over the
            // existing texture
            DrawNode *line = DrawNode::create();
            line->drawSegment(nodeStart, nodeEnd, 20, Color4F::BLACK);
            line->visit();

        } rt->end();


        // We mask current texture with the mask texture using a custom shader. The resulting texture will then be
        // affected to the zone's texture, making a new texture that can be used again next function call.
        Texture2D *currentTexture = zone->getTexture();
        Texture2D *maskTexture = rt->getSprite()->getTexture();
        maskTexture->setAliasTexParameters(); // Disable linear interpolation on the mask

        // Setup the shader for currentTexture
        // Custom shader is already loaded in the init method of GroundLayer
        currentTexture->setShaderProgram(ShaderCache::getInstance()->getProgram(CustomShader_AlphaMask_frag_key));
        GLProgram *shader = currentTexture->getShaderProgram();
        int maskTexUniformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader->getProgram(), "u_alphaMaskTexture");
        glUniform1i(maskTexUniformLoc, 1);

        // Actually apply the shader over currentTexture
        shader->use();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, maskTexture->getName());
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

        // [I'm at lost here :( (or sooner...)]
    }
}
```

Here's the shader I wrote:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_alphaMaskTexture;

void main() {

    // Mask the texture with the alpha of the texture
    float maskAlpha = texture2D(u_alphaMaskTexture, v_texCoord).a;
    float texAlpha = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;
    float blendAlpha = (1.0 - maskAlpha) * texAlpha; // Show only where mask is invisible

    vec3 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).rgb;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor, blendAlpha);

    return;
}
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Edited, sorry.

Comment: OK, retracted close vote. Good luck ...